# Como expor portas UDP no arquivo de configuração do docker-compose?

Tags: docker

Tenho o seguinte arquivo `docker-compose.yml`  e gostaria de expor alguma das portas como UDP.

```
version: "3.0"
services: 
  myservice: 
    image: "my/service"
    ports: 
      - "40061:4061"
      - "40062:4062"
      - "5684:5684" <--- UDP
      - "5683:5683" <--- UDP
  mongo: 
    image: "mongo:3.4"
```

Parece que o padrão é expor essas portas como TCP, então  o serviço externo não está acessando.

Como ficaria a configuração no docker-compose para que fosse possível expor essas portas como UDP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para expor a porta como UDP, basta adicionar no final do mapeamento `/udp`. Usando a sua *compose* como exemplo, passaríamos a ter isto:

```
version: "3.0"
services: 
  myservice: 
    image: "my/service"
    ports: 
      - "40061:4061"
      - "40062:4062"
      - "5684:5684/udp"
      - "5683:5683/udp"
  mongo: 
    image: "mongo:3.4"
```

Ao verificarmos os *status* dos serviços com *docker-compose ps* veríamos as portas como UDP, algo assim:

```
Name                     Command                  State         Ports           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dockerudp_mongo_1        docker-entrypoint.sh     Up            27017/tcp                 
                         mongod                                                            
dockerudp_myservice_1    /bin/sh -c whatever.sh   Up            0.0.0.0:40061->4061/tcp,  
                                                                0.0.0.0:40062->4062/tcp,  
                                                                0.0.0.0:5683->5683/udp,   
                                                                0.0.0.0:5684->5684/udp
```

É importante lembrar que na sua imagem, a `my/service` construída, devem ter também expostas as portas como UDP, ou seja, deve conter uma instrução como esta:

```
EXPOSE 5683/udp 5684/udp
```